# Certain variable not able to be defined?

Tags: python

Just in case someone takes this down yes, I went looking for the answer before hand. So I am working on a small personal project and I became stuck (Just so you know I'm very new to Python). I'll show you what I mean

```
joke = input("Want to hear a funny joke?\n")
if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
    chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
    print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
else:
    print("Awww..")
```

What I'm trying to get to happen here is python will ask you if you want to hear a joke, if you say no it will go "Awww.." and if you say yes it will ask you why did the chicken cross the road. It works when I say yes but when I say no it gives this

```
Want to hear a funny joke?
no
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python projects\Python Buddie.py", line 34, in <module>
    if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
NameError: name 'chicken' is not defined
```

I have chicken defined as you can see. I feel like I'm getting an order wrong, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
    chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
    print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
```

What happens if `joke` is **not** `in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']`?

Then `chicken` is not defined. You should either have the second `if` inside the first `if`, or define `chicken` beforehand:

```
if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
    chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
    if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
        print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
```

or

```
chicken = None
if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
    chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
    print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: What about the part where you say no, it doesn't go aww?

Comment: @DeanGullberry You can leave it where it is. I only focused on the problematic part.

Answer (score 0):

You put the else in the wrong place, that's why

Your else statement is follow by when the user already say yes

To Fix this:

```
joke = input("Want to hear a funny joke?\n") 

if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
  chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
  if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
     print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
else:
  print("Awww..")
```

Comment: try again and make sure all code are in-line and match regulated indentation for python 2.7.x or 3.0x

Answer (score 0):

Python provides no braces to indicate blocks of code for class and function definitions or flow control. Blocks of code are denoted by line indentation, which is rigidly enforced.

And Error is just because of wrong indentation.

```
joke = input("Want to hear a funny joke?\n")
if joke in ['yes', 'ya', 'sure', 'ok', 'fine', 'yeah']:
    chicken = input("Why did the chicken cross the road?\n")
    if chicken in ["To get to the other side", "to get to the other side"]:
        print("HAHAHAHAHAHHAHH OMG LOLZZZ FUNNY JOKE RIGHT!!!!!!!")
else:
    print("Awww..")
```